# Frame within frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm making a simple arithmetic game.

The first frame is a login screen, next this will close and then open a new frame after the user is logged in.

In the next frame, you can choose buttons which represent the game's modes and when I click a button a new frame opens.

What I am trying to accomplish is that I want is to continue working within this new frame. I don't want to keep moving between frames.

I am trying to make a back button for each mode so I can return to the original modes frame. I am only using the two frames for my program.

Is there a way I can choose the mode then go to a new screen and still be able to go back to the mode selection frame?

Comment: When you say "frame", do you mean a separate dialog (like what a jframe would give), or just a different "panel" in the same dialog (aka, switching panels in the frame)?

Comment: yeah, something like that. like clicking a button on your browser opens the page in your browser(unless you instruct it to open in a new window)

Comment: use jpanels or JinternalPanes

Answer (score -1):

You could have 2 JPanels and when you press a button, an action listener does
`Frame.remove(Panel1);
 Frame.add(Panel2);`